# Como guardar los datos de un préstamo en un solo campo de mi Base de Datos

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de préstamo de herramientas en Java y en  mi base de datos tengo la tabla `HERRAMIENTAS`, tabla `CLIENTES` y tabla `PRESTAMOS`.El detalle está en que cuando un cliente solicite varias herramientas cómo las guardo en la tabla `PRESTAMOS`, específicamente en el campo `idHerra`, ya que un cliente puede solicitar una o varias herramientas por cada préstamo.

---

```
create table herramientas
(
idHerra  int not null auto_increment,
nombreHerra varchar(30) not null, 
descripcionHerra varchar(50) not null,
stockHerra int,
PRIMARY KEY (idHerra)
 )

create table clientes
(
idCliente int not null auto_increment,
nombreCliente varchar(30) not null, 
appCliente varchar(30) not null,
apmCliente varchar(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (idCliente)
)

create table prestamosHerramienta
(
idPres int not null  AUTO_INCREMENT,
fechaPres DATETIME,
Observaciones varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (idPres),
idCliente int,
idHerra int,
)
ADD FOREIGN KEY (idCliente) REFERENCES clientes (idCliente); 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (idHerra) REFERENCES herramientas (idHerra);
```

Comment: es un registro por herramienta, o sea un registro por prestamo. Si no es lo que estas preguntando, no entiendo cual es tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Dada la estructura de la tabla `prestamoHerramienta` debes crear un nuevo registro por cada herramienta que un cliente preste. Por ejemplo, si el cliente 1 presta las herramientas 1,2 y 3 el día de hoy, este sería el contenido de tu tabla:

```
idPres      fechaPres                 Observaciones idCliente   idHerra     
----------- ------------------------- ------------ ----------- ----------- 
1           2018-02-01 09:35:47.71    Ninguna      1           1           
2           2018-02-01 09:35:47.71    Ninguna      1           2           
3           2018-02-01 09:35:47.71    Ninguna      1           3
```

Creo que lo que estás intentando hacer es lo siguiente:

```
idPres      fechaPres                 Observaciones idCliente   idHerra 
----------- ------------------------- ------------ ----------- ------- 
1           2018-02-01 09:40:28.403   Ninguna      1           1,2,3
```

Esto no es posible debido a que el tipo de dato de `idHerra` es de tipo `int`, no una lista o conjunto de `int`, por lo tanto solo puede almacenar un solo id. Podrías convertir el campo a un tipo de dato varchar y concatenar los ids que un cliente preste y luego almacenarlo, pero esto implicaría más esfuerzo de programación, tanto para el ingreso como para la consulta de datos.

Y hablando de consulta de datos, supongamos que te piden un reporte de cual es el número de veces que cada herramienta se presta. ¿Cómo lo harías si tuvieras en un solo campo todos los ids que un cliente presta? Tendrías que recuperar TODOS los registros en una estructura de java (y eso no es eficiente para nada, conforme crezca el volumen de datos), separar los ids del campo `IdHerra` y luego hacer un conteo de cada id de las herramientas, todo esto a nivel de java. En tanto que con el modelo relacional que tienes es tan simple como esta consulta:

```
select  idHerra, count(1)
from    prestamosHerramienta
group by (idHerra)
```

> Actualización

Al parecer el problema es como realizar el préstamo en el formulario/ventana de la aplicación.

En ese caso las respuestas son muy subjetivas y variadas:

1. Al levantar el formulario de préstamo, puedes consultar la tabla de herramientas, generar controles de tipo `checkbox` dinámicamente para cada uno de los id de herramientas obtenidos. De esta manera, seleccionas el cliente y luego marcas que herramientas va a prestar. Luego, por cada `checkbox` marcado ingresas un registro.
2. Creas una rejilla que se le puedan añadir filas y en cada fila escribes un id de herramienta. Luego al realizar el préstamo recorres la rejilla y por cada fila ingresas un registro.
3. Agrega un botón "Añadir herramienta" que cada vez que lo pulses, te deje un ingresar un id de herramienta, y lo vas concatenando en una variable de tipo string separados por algún caracter especial, por ejemplo "|". Luego, al realizar el prestamo, separas los ids de esta variable y por cada uno ingresas un registro.
4. Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Lo que mencionas es precisamente lo que quiero hacer pero no encuentro la forma de realizar.

Comment: @Damii aclara que es lo que no podes hacer?? y si es separar las herramientas como 1,2,3.. entonces no, esta mal y no se hace asi.

Comment: Si es que no encuentro la forma de hacerlo desde mi formulario registroPrestamo en java, mas que nada en el jTextField idHerramienta para que cada préstamo incluya varias herramientas y guardarlo en la tabla prestamoHerramienta de mi bd.